# In Go, can JSON marshaling of a well-defined type ever fail?

Tags: go, error-handling

Given the following code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Employee struct {
    Id int "json:id"
}

func main() {
    b, err := json.Marshal(&Employee{Id: 2})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Couldn't marshal the Employee")
    }

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Can checking for the error be reliably ignored using the `_` placeholder since the `Employee` struct is well defined.  Theoretically it should never fail, so begs the question is it a good practice to ignore this type of error and save a little on this type of boilerplate error checking?

Ignoring would look like so:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Employee struct {
    Id int "json:id"
}

func main() {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(&Employee{Id: 2})
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

Comment: Well, typically this won't fail. There is nothing Employee itself which could go wrong. But one never knows, especially as structs tend to grow but no one will check the marshaling. Add a field `Boss *Employee`, combine with a bug where e.Boss == e and kaboom: Marshaling fails and you won't see the error. **Never** ignore any error.

Comment: I'm with @Volker on this: instead of ignoring this error merely `panic` on it. It's only a single check for `nil` slower but won't subject you to a possibility of a hard-to-find bug. If you feel like this, create a helper function `MustMarshal()`.

Comment: Yes, I generally do always check for errors...but this question was more about understanding the possibility of an error occurring from a well-defined type.  I agree, that as code grows and gets more complicated relying on this fact could come back to bite me if I ignore it as a practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Error handling and Go](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go):

> Proper error handling is an essential requirement of good software.

---

Normally your code won't fail. but if user Adds this `MarshalJSON` method reciver to your type, it fails:

```golang
func (t *Employee) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if t.Id == 2 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Forbiden Id = %d", t.Id)
    }
    data := []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"Id":%d}`, t.Id))
    return data, nil
}
```

---

This code Compiles, but fails on purpose just for `Id == 2` ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cR42CzrbH5)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Employee struct {
    Id int "json:id"
}

func main() {
    b, err := json.Marshal(&Employee{Id: 2})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Couldn't marshal the Employee", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

func (t *Employee) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if t.Id == 2 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Forbiden Id = %d", t.Id)
    }
    data := []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`{"Id":%d}`, t.Id))
    return data, nil
}
```

---

Also this code Compiles, but fails ([The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Lm6w1gIsnG)):

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Employee struct {
    Id int "json:id"
}

func main() {
    b, err := json.Marshal(&Employee{Id: 2})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Couldn't marshal the Employee")
    }

    fmt.Println(string(b))
}

func (t Employee) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    data := []byte(fmt.Sprint(t))
    return data, nil
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

You can always write your own "wrapper" packages to compose behavior that might otherwise be boilerplate. For example, if you have a logging system set up, you might build a small package that looks like:

```
package json
import (
  "encoding/json"
  "log"
)
func TryMarshal(v interface{}) []byte {
  b, err := json.Marshal(v)
  if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
    return nil
  }
  return b
}
```